# RAM compression. Why hasn't it caught on?

Tags: memory

I was reading an journal on Hardware Compression of RAM and I was wondering why something like this hasn't become commonly used. Something like this would be really useful to servers or the kid at home who's rendering video for his Minecraft channel.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.122.3232&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: What makes you imagine that compression isn't used already?

Comment: Because ive never heard about it before, is it already used in consumer desktops?

Comment: See my answer. I think compression is used in specific cases where it has benefits. It is just not built-into the hardware.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap and http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/hardware/whitepapers/am_exp_perf.html

Comment: the ARM processor Thumb instruction actively uses compression on the op- codes to save space in embedded systems.

Comment: @placeholder - I think I understand what you mean, ARM Thumb provides a more compact representation of popular instructions and hence gets more instructions per kB of memory; MIPS microMIPS is a similar architecture concept. However, I don't think Joshua Waring means that. I think the question is about dynamic compression. Though I am happy to receive clarification :-)

Comment: @gbulmer that's why I only commented and didn't answer, but instructions are sometimes moved to RAM in these systems so it's not so black and white.

Comment: Because memory is cheaper and more reliable than software or firmware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, **in general**, lossless compression can never achieve a better rate than 2x (I think there was some proof about that which implied that for 'somewhat random' data there are diminishing returns. I'll try to find that). We have to consider the general case because the compression hardware is built in.

Lossy compression, like MPEG JPEG can do *much* better, but that is useless for computer programs and data. Compression becomes less effective the more 'random' the data, so, it could actually get to a stage where built-in compression offers no actual compression.

The shorter the compressed object, the more memory storage overhead we'd expect for the compression scheme, reducing its effectiveness. For example, to ensure random access still works, memory addresses would have to be mappable to compressed memory, which would likely waste space somewhere.

In return for compression, main memory latency will likely increase to allow the compression hardware to work. Main memory is already very, very much slower than the CPU, with significant latency. So adding more latency seems like a fundamentally 'bad idea'. The mismatch between CPU speed and memory speed has been getting worse (partly because of multiple cores sharing a memory bus) for many years. So a paper written in 2000 might not have fully considered this.

IBM's Power series CPU's can use compression on the instructions. They can decode to the normal instruction patterns before the CPU uses the instructions.

Edit3: It makes much more sense to compress read-only data than read-write data. A large block of read-only data can be compressed once, which is cheap. Instruction code is a very good candidate for compression because on most OSs, and many languages code is read-only or even execute-only (it can't be read as data by user programs). The case against this is some CPU Instruction Set Architectures (ISAs), are already densely encoded so it might not give as much benefit as it might appear.

Most modern programming languages include compression functions in their libraries. So a programmer can choose to compress chunks of data which might benefit. The programmer has enough knowledge to select between lossy and lossless compression which could yield bigger benefits than a blanket lossless technique. A programmer using compression would actually be bad for a built-in compression scheme because compressed data is very hard to compress (when using a good scheme). So a situation where lossy compression of specific data is 'good', and would yield much better compression than a lossless scheme would make compression worse!

Edit3:
[OS X "Mavericks" Compressed Memory (page 8)](https://www.apple.com/media/us/osx/2013/docs/OSX_Mavericks_Core_Technology_Overview.pdf) explains that the OS X "Mavericks" does compress data for *inactive* applications.

Linux also has [memory compression mechanisms](http://lwn.net/Articles/545244/) in the kernel. That article explains that it uses pages as the unit of compression, so there are already in-kernel tables to track them, and hence existing structures can be extended. Further, the underlying CPU hardware will 'interrupt' on access to a page, which is exactly the right time to uncompress that page.

As pointed out in comments, IBM's AIX has [Active memory Expansion](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/hardware/whitepapers/am_exp.html) too.

{ Comment: If someone can find the Windows, BSD, etc. versions which identify *in-RAM* compression, I will add those too. }

Just to be clear, I am not saying the referenced paper, using specific compression hardware is necessarily a bad idea.

I would expect doing memory compression using the CPU is relatively 'expensive'. It is likely reading memory sequentially, which is typically the definition of a 'cache buster'. It is imaginable that OSs switch off wholesale cache eviction for the memory being compressed, while doing compression. Hence doing work before the cache seems like it might be useful.

One model might be a 'smart' DMA controller which could do compression or decompression as it copies memory. That might be more obvious, easy to integrate into an existing OS, and be visible enough to the CPU and memory controller hardware that it might have minimal impact.

Edit:
It's *irrelevant* that a specific case have lossless compression which beats 2x. Specific cases do not matter. Write 20,000 0 bytes to a file, and run a lossless compression system, and the file will become tiny. That is not evidence that in the general case lossless compression *always* achieves better than 2x compression, merely that it might in some specific cases.

Instead, we need to demonstrate that lossless compression can achieve better than 2x in *all* cases, especially the *worst* cases, and *random data* cases. That is the point. Once the compression hardware is built in, there is no choice, unless the scheme becomes even even more complex. With even more complexity, I would expect wasted space, a cognate of memory fragmentation, to become worse.

Edit 2:
I have skimmed the paper. IMHO a significant weakness appears to be it doesn't deal with the cost of the electronics vs alternative uses of that spend. I would be surprised if significant cost applied to several areas of a CPU might not yield benefits. IMHO, it is *not* enough to say 'add this extra stuff, and this property of a system gets better'. It needs to be done in comparison with one or more alternatives. So, for example, it might be cheaper to just buy more memory!

My $0.02

Comment: I can actually think of lots of situations in which lossless compression can far exceed 2x. For an excellent example, create a text file containing four thousand iterations of the space-delimited word "test", like "test test test...". Save that file and note that it contains 20,000 bytes. Now compress it with gzip or WinZip and note its size in the compressed state.

Comment: IBM's CodePack seems to have been abandoned in favor of supporting Power's new VLE extension. Mentioning OS X's use of compressed memory to avoid swapping might be worthwhile. IBM's AIX has [Active Memory Expansion](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/hardware/whitepapers/am_exp.html) (I just notice [jippie's comment](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/126292/15426#comment-252932) mentioning this.)

Comment: That reads better - thanks... and good point about double-compressing having an efficiency cost. Still, there may be some value in **optional** hardware-controlled memory compression; some OSs provide optional on-the-fly hard-drive compression, which is a close equivalent. It **does** come with a latency cost, of course, but memory compression would relieve paging-to-disk latency, so may result in a significant overall speed increase. I do think it should be optional rather than forced.

Comment: @TDHofstetter - agreed, optional compression might work. I have cited three OSs which do that.

Comment: @gbulmer - Windows (at least >=XP, not sure about 95/98/ME/NT/2K) has optional on-the-fly compression; from Windows Explorer, one can pick a directory or complete drive, right-click, pick "Properties", and click the "Advanced" button. On the next dialog, you're offered the option of compressing the drive/directory. If you choose compression, that drive/directory will use dynamic compression until you turn the option back off. Solaris, too, supports ZFS, which can do transparent compression.

Comment: @TDHofstetter - I interpret the question to be about in-memory compression, not disk compression. Disk compression has very different dynamics. For example a system call must be executed before reading a file. Compressing on write, and decompression on read may enable disk access to have higher throughput, etc. In-memory compression may reduce memory bandwidth, and latency is a main memory read.

Comment: @gbulmer - my latter comment to you was in response to your "{Comment: If someone can find the Windows, BSD, etc. versions, I will add those too.}". The original question at hand is definitely about compression in RAM, not about compression on disk. Compression in RAM will very likely introduce RAM latency but may reduce page-file activity and in reducing paging may actually improve RAM latency & bandwidth in the larger view.

Comment: @TDHofstetter - Okay. I hadn't expected comments to go off topic to disk compression. However, I have tried to clarify my comment as being about In-RAM compression. Reducing paging won't change RAM latency or RAM bandwidth, but it could improve system throughput.

Comment: @gbulmer Yes, my [survey paper on data compression](https://www.academia.edu/12429529/A_Survey_Of_Architectural_Approaches_for_Data_Compression_in_Cache_and_Main_Memory_Systems) provides references on why realizing more than 2X compression is difficult. E.g., metadata overhead becomes large, e.g., to get 4X compression in cache, we need 4X tags also. Also, cache replacement becomes difficult.

Answer (score 1):

DRAM has today very low power consumption when idle. Because both servers and smartphones aren't as much hardware cost limited as they are power limited, until a power consumption advantage of using compression can be demonstrated, compression will not, in general, be used in these areas. Multi-level caching system will be preferred instead, with various successive kinds of memory having lower power requirements and higher capacity.

Software RAM compression has been indeed used to retrofit older or weaker systems to running software that they are not trivially suitable for because of RAM requirements and lack of scratch disk storage. However, a power consumption increase has been obvious (*this is disputed, see discussion below). It has also been used to increase performance of units where scratch disk is prohibitively slow.

It's likely the case that with hardware support, a RAM compression system could be implemented at lower power requirements than purely in software. However this goes against the goal of retrofitting otherwise unsuitable equipment as above, and doesn't appear to be demonstrably useful for newly designed equipment.

Comment: "However, a power consumption increase has been obvious." Please provide a reference for that assertion. Apple claim ["Mavericks" Compressed Memory](https://www.apple.com/media/us/osx/2013/docs/OSX_Mavericks_Core_Technology_Overview.pdf) 'Improves power efficiency'. A quick search of the web has failed to find anyone disputing that claim.

Comment: I can see how it would decrease power consumption in a PC if it allows to completely power down the harddrive for a longer period of time. I think this claim for Mavericks will be one which will turn out true or false depending on the test case and it will be impossible to decide.

XDADev community have some experience with zram (compressed swap to RAM) on Android, and i recall the discussion that for devices with severe memory contention, it did increase power consumption, which were pretty much the only class of devices they were seriously trying it on; but i can't find it now.

Comment: Here's a thread which discusses the power impact of enabling compcache (prior version of zram) on Palm Pre, a WebOS device with 265MB RAM: http://forums.webosnation.com/palm-pre-pre-plus/251638-govnah-compcache-battery-drain.html

Comment: HTC Hero users also found that compcache may cut their idle time significantly: http://www.modaco.com/topic/300838-compcache-yea-or-nay/page-3

Unfortunately there are no good controlled experiments on this topic or a scientific work that i'm aware of, so getting reliable data will be hard.

Comment: Agreed, those threads don't seem to indicate anything consistent.